# How i setup PHPMailer in HTML over Visual Studio (Not a Asp project)?

Tags: php, html, visual-studio, phpmailer, contact-form

I have a problem with PHPMailer. I developed HTML project over Visual Studio Empty Project. I wanna design contact form with PHPMailer because of the server where the project will be loaded is working with PHP(cPanel). I add PHPMailer: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer, configure SMTP mail system. Everything is OK I think, but that error when form sending:

> "Fatal error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found in /ssd2/myplastech/public_html/test/PHPMailer/src/Index.php on line 29"

I try to all directions solutions but, I didn't solve this problem. What can I do?

*Related Parts->*

HTML Form:

```
<form id="contact-form" action="PHPMailer/src/Index.php" method="post">
...
<input type="submit" name="buttonsubmit" id="btn-contact-form"></input>
```

composer.json:

```
"require": {
"php": ">=5.5.0",
"phpmailer/phpmailer": "~6.1",
"ext-ctype": "*",
"ext-filter": "*" },
```

Index.php:

```
include 'PHPMailer.php';
include 'SMTP.php';
include 'Exception.php';
//Load Composer's autoloader
//require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
```

Do I need to add the vendor or `'vendor/autoload.php'` externally? Where can I add if I add?

Comment: Please read [the instructions on how to load PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#installation--loading), and base your code on one of the examples provided, paying special attention to the namespacing.

Comment: I made adjustments based on this article. Where exactly do you want to emphasize? @Synchro

Comment: You should read it again, since you are not loading it the way the docs suggest, and you're not paying attention to the namespacing (those `use` statements you don't have), which is what is causing the fatal error. All would be avoided if you started with one of the example scripts.